# Does MySQL have a way to "coalesce" as an aggregate function?

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to take an existing application and re-architect the schema to support new customer requests and fix several outstanding issues (mostly around our current schema being heavily denormalized). In doing so, I've reached an interesting problem which at first glance seems to have a simple solution, but I can't seem to find the function I'm looking for.

The application is a media organization tool.

### Our Old Schema:

Our old schema had separate models for "Groups", "Subgroups", and "Videos". A Group could have many Subgroups (one-to-many) and a Subgroup could have many Videos (one-to-many).

There were certain fields that were shared among Groups, Subgroups, and Videos. For instance, the Google Analytics ID to be used when the Video was embedded on a page. Whenever we displayed the embed page we would first look if the value was set on the Video. If not, we checked its Subgroup. If not, we checked its Group. The query looked roughly like so (I wish this were the real query, but unfortunately our application was written over many years by many junior developers, so the truth is much more painful):

```
SELECT
    v.id,
    COALESCE(v.google_analytics_id, sg.google_analytics_id, g.google_analytics_id) as google_analytics_id
FROM
    Videos v
    LEFT JOIN Subgroups sg ON sg.id = v.subgroup_id
    LEFT JOIN Groups g ON g.id = sg.group_id
```

Pretty straight-forward. Now the issue we've run into is that customers want to be able to nest groups arbitrarily deep, and our schema clearly only allows for 2 levels (and, in fact, ***necessitates*** two levels - even if you only want one)

### New Schema (First Pass):

As a first pass, I knew we'd want a basic tree structure for the Groups, so I came up with this:

```
CREATE TABLE Groups (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    parent_id INT,
    ga_id VARCHAR(20)
)
```

We can then easily nest up to N levels deep with N joins like so:

```
SELECT
    v.id,
    COALESCE(v.ga_id, g1.ga_id, g2.ga_id, g3.ga_id, ...) as ga_id
FROM
    Videos v
    LEFT JOIN Groups g1 ON g1.id = v.group_id
    LEFT JOIN Groups g2 ON g2.id = g1.parent_id
    LEFT JOIN Groups g3 ON g3.id = g2.parent_id
    ...
```

There's obvious flaws with this approach: We don't know how many parents there will be so we don't know how many times we should JOIN, forcing us to implement a "max depth". Then even with a max depth, if a person only has a single level of groups we still perform multiple JOINs because our queries can't know how deep they need to go. MySQL offers recursive queries, but while looking into if that was the right option I found a smarter schema that produced the same results

### New Schema (Take 2):

Looking into better ways to handle a tree structure, I learned about Adjacency Lists (my prior solution), Nested Sets, Materialized Paths, and Closure Tables. Other than Adjacency Lists (which depend on JOINs to grab the entire tree structure and so produces a single row with multiple columns per node on the tree), the other three solutions all return multiple rows for each node on the tree

I ended up going with a Closure Table solution like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Groups (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    ga_id VARCHAR(20)
)
CREATE TABLE Group_Closure (
    ancestor_id INT,
    descendant_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ancestor_id, descendant_id)
)
```

Now given a Video I can get all of its parents like so:

```
SELECT
    v.id,
    v.ga_id,
    g.id,
    g.ga_id
FROM
    Videos v
    JOIN Group_Closure gc ON v.group_id = gc.descendant
    JOIN Groups g ON g.id = gc.ancestor;
```

This returns each group in the hierarchy as a separate row:

```
+------+---------+------+---------+
| v.id | v.ga_id | g.id | g.ga_id |
+------+---------+------+---------+
|   1  |  abc123 |   2  | new_val |
|   1  |  abc123 |   1  | default |
|   2  |   NULL  |   4  |  xyz987 |
|   2  |   NULL  |   3  |   NULL  |
|   2  |   NULL  |   1  | default |
|   3  |   NULL  |   3  |   NULL  |
|   3  |   NULL  |   1  | default |
+------+---------+------+---------+
```

What I wish to do now is somehow achieve the same result I would have expected from using `COALESCE` on multiple self-joined Group tables: a single value for `ga_id` based on whichever node is "lowest" in the tree

Because I have multiple rows per Video, I suspect that this can be accomplished using `GROUP BY` and some kind of aggregate function:

```
SELECT
    v.id,
    COALESCE(v.ga_id, FIRST_NON_NULL(g.ga_id))
FROM
    Videos v
    JOIN Group_Closure gc ON v.group_id = gc.descendant
    JOIN Groups g ON g.id = gc.ancestor
GROUP BY v.id, v.ga_id;
```

Note that because `(ancestor, descendant)` is my primary key, I believe the order of the group closure table can be guaranteed to always come back the same - meaning if I put the lowest node first, it will be the first row in the resulting query... If my understanding of this is incorrect, please let me know.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick MySQL 8.0.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to stick with an adjacency list, you could use a recursive CTE. This one traverses up from each `video` id value until it finds a non-`NULL` `ga_id`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (
  SELECT id, ga_id, group_id
  FROM videos
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CTE.id, COALESCE(CTE.ga_id, g.ga_id), g.parent_id
  FROM `groups` g
  JOIN CTE ON g.id = CTE.group_id AND CTE.ga_id IS NULL
)
SELECT id, ga_id
FROM CTE
WHERE ga_id IS NOT NULL
```

For my attempt to reconstruct your data from your question, this yields:

```
id  ga_id
1   abc123
2   xyz987
3   default
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7MS235KEE8VRfWPV7U1eVV/0)

Comment: This does seem to work, although I'm not familiar enough with recursive queries yet to wrap my head around exactly how or why it's working. Ideally I'd prefer an answer that wasn't dependent on MySQL 8 features for portability (in case we switch to Postgres or something) - but this at least is functional for the time being until a better solution comes along (assuming one ever will). Out of curiosity, do you know what the performance impact of a recursive query is? Using a Closure Table takes only two JOIN operations and one table scan, so it's pretty fast.

Comment: @stevendesu pretty much all DBMS support recursive CTEs (MySQL was catching up with version 8). I'm not familiar enough with Closure tables (something to read up on in lockdown!) to know for sure if you can rely on the ordering that you need. Performance wise it is likely to depend on how deep you have to search for a valid `ga_id`. This could require as little as one join, as many as the entire tree depth, although the joins will get smaller on each pass.

Comment: I've just tested this morning and short of the backtick operator causing some fuss in Postgres (rather than look up the proper syntax, I just renamed `groups` to `video_groups` so I didn't need them) it looks like the recursive CTE works in Postgres, Sqlite, ***and*** MySQL 8. So this is likely the best way for me to go. Thank you

Comment: Ah yes - in PostgreSQL you'd need double quotes. As you say, easier to rename it to a non-reserved word. I'm glad it's working for you.

Comment: I dumped a ton of dummy data to a database to start experimenting with you recursive query and ran into two issues. First, I noticed you have `AND CTE.ga_id IS NULL` in your `JOIN`. If I have multiple different settings (not just `ga_id`) then they may be set on various levels of the recursive query. So I don't know if this solution works for more than one column. Second, once I had 500,000 videos (close to our production dataset) the recursive query was ***slooooow***. It took 12 seconds to run! Unfortunately this is a query that needs to be run VERY often.

Comment: @stevendesu this solution (as is) won't work for more than one column although it can be expanded to do so. The speed issue is harder to deal with... I had a bit of a play with your closure groups structure [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7MS235KEE8VRfWPV7U1eVV/3) that query should work as long as parent groups always have lower `id` values than their children. If that doesn't help, could you perhaps create a dbfiddle with more sample data - it might also be a good idea to start a new question, referring back to this one so you don't get the same answer from someone else.